# AssertionError using pyinstaller with protobuf on M1 Mac

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, pyinstaller, apple-m1, arm64

I am getting this error when I try to use pyinstaller to create an executable of my code.

```
AssertionError: /Users/arlinsandbulte/PycharmProjects/Pr07-Media-Sweeper/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.cpython-310-darwin.so is incompatible with target arch arm64 (has arch: x86_64)!
```

Here is the pyinstaller command I am using:

```
pyinstaller "Pro7 Media Sweeper.py" -p ./Pro7-File-API-Python/ -F -w --i resource_files/icons/sweeper.icns --add-data './resource_files:resource_files'
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured this out, at least a work-around.
I just added the option: `--target-arch x86_64` to the pyinstaller command.  And that worked!
This means the package is x86_64 and needs to run through Rosetta instead of being a Universal 2 binary.